# RxUI.NET - Hiding a message after a period of time

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm toying with Reactive UI and I'd like to show a message after a process is completed and hide this message after a period of time (4 sec). If the messages keep coming faster than is the period for hiding, the timeout should be reset, so the message is always hidden after 4 seconds after the last message is displayed/updated. The hiding should be also prolonged if the last message is the same as previous.

Currently I have this code, which does what I want, but it looks too cumbersome to me. I'm just experimenting with the RxUI, so most of the time I don't know what I'm doing. Are there better ways how to achieve this?

```
public class MainViewModel: ReactiveObject
{
  // Message to be shown.
  private string message;
  public string Message { get => message; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref message, value);

  // Flag for the UI, if the message panel should be visible.
  private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> isMessageVisible;
  public bool IsMessageVisible => isMessageVisible.Value;

  // Command that runs async process, the result is the message to be shown.
  public ReactiveCommand<Unit, string> Run { get; private set; }  

  public MainViewModel()
  {        
    var msg = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Message, x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

    // If message changes, after 4 seconds return false, causing hiding the message panel.
    var hide = msg.Select(x => false).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);

    // Merge both sequences into one output property.
    Observable.Merge(msg, hide).ToProperty(this, x => x.IsMessageVisible, out isMessageVisible);

    Run = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => Observable.StartAsync(Process));

    // Merge various message sources and set message property. Set Message = null to force property change.
    Observable.Merge(Run, Run.ThrownExceptions.Select(x => x.Message)).Subscribe(x => { Message = null; Message = x; });      
  }    
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I'd declare `isMessageVisible` like this:

```
isMessageVisible = this
    .WhenAnyValue(x => x.Message, x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    .Select(showMessage => Observable.Return(showMessage).Concat(Observable.Return(false).Delay(4, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)))
    .Switch()
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsMessageVisible);
```

It puts all the logic together in one pipeline, which I think is more readable.

---

Apart from rewriting `isMessageVisible`, I'd change how the messages are displayed in the first place.

I'd drop `isMessageVisible` and only have the `Message` property. When `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message) == true` hide the message in the UI, and when `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message) == false` show the UI. This would be something like this with RxUI bindings:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Message, v => v.Message.Text, message => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(message));
```

Then I'd do this in the view model:

```
public class MainViewModel: ReactiveObject
{
    // Message to be shown.
    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> message;
    public string Message => message.Value;

    // Command that runs async process, the result is the message to be shown.
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, string> Run { get; private set; }  

    public MainViewModel()
    {   
        Run = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => Observable.StartAsync(Process));

        // Merge various message sources and set message property.
        message = Observable.Merge(Run, Run.ThrownExceptions.Select(x => x.Message))
            .Select(msg => Observable.Return(msg).Concat(Observable.Return("").Delay(4, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler))) // 1
            .Switch() // 2
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.Message);
    }
}
```

1. This will return the new message immediately and then return an empty string after 4 seconds
2. This will only subscribe to the most recent observable returned by `Select`. If a new message is sent the previous observable will not send the empty string

If you have multiple commands returning messages you can add a convenience function to reduce the amount of code:

```
private IObservable<string> CreateMessageStream(params ReactiveCommand<Unit, string> commands)
    => Observable.Merge(commands.SelectMany(command => new IObservable<string>[] { command, command.ThrownExceptions.Select(x => x.Message) }))
        .Select(msg => Observable.Return(msg).Concat(Observable.Return("").Delay(4, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)))
        .Switch()
```

Then you can declare `message` like this:

```
message = CreateMessageStream(Run, Walk, Crawl)
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Message);
```

Where `Run`, `Walk` and `Crawl` are all `ReactiveCommand`s.

Comment: Great answer. It seems one has to completely change mindset to be effective with the Rx/UI. Thanks.